# No user can do task=registration.activate?

Tags: registration, acl, joomla-user-groups, weblinks, super-user

From the page to activate a registered user, I am seeing some unexpected permission messages.

e.g. example.com/web2020/index.php/s-inscrire?**task=registration.activate**&token=d1ab2d55df409df9fff55899999999

> Message:
>
> COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_ACL_ADMIN_ACTIVATION : 
>   Please log in to confirm that you are authorised to activate new accounts.

Connection of a "SuperUser"

> Error:
>
> JERROR_ALERTNOAUTHOR : 
>   You are not authorised to view this resource.

*Shouldn't a super user be allowed to do everything?*

This user does not want to *View*, but to *Do* something! Shouldn't they receive the following message?

> COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_ACL_ADMIN_ACTIVATION_PERMISSIONS
>   You are not authorised to activate new accounts, please log in with a privileged account.

Comment: By default, yes, but you have to check your permissions. Check if the `activate` function has something verifying whether the user has permission or not or your view.

Comment: @Christine I have attempted to improve the English, but if I have somehow damaged the intent of your post, please re-edit your question so that it is accurate.  If you edit the question, please do not put any k's in the word "something" -- even if that is the way that you pronounce it -- researchers who use translating or screen reading software will have an easier time if correct spelling and grammar are used.  Welcome to JSE and thank you for contributing. Please take our [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution :
The administrator must also belong to the Guest group.

Comment: The system has flagged this answer as low-quality due to its length/content.  Please not only express the solution, but how/why it solves the problem with the intent to educate/empower future Joomla researchers.  After doing so, if this technique resolves your question, please award your own answer with the big green tick to mark the page as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

On the site, two menu items lead respectively to

- registration form (item "S'inscrire")
- login form (item "Connexion")

For each menu item, a Viewing Access Level is chosen.

For these menu items, the "Guest" Viewing Access Level would be preferable to the "Public" level because, once logged in, who needs a login screen?

But the "Guest" level *will cause the registration procedure to fail* ; not the "Public" level.

In the general settings, we ask that the registration of new users be approved by a Site Administrator.

First attempt : the "Guest" level is chosen.

An administrator receives an e-mail with the following activation link : https://www.clapiedsrando.fr/web2020/index.php/s-inscrire?task=registration.activate&token=d1ab2dxxxxxxxxxxxx

He activates this link; the site answers: COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_ACL_ADMIN_ACTIVATION

The administrator logs in; the site replies: JERROR_ALERTNOAUTHOR *and the procedure fails.*

In a second attempt, the Viewing Access Level is set to "Public".

The administrator logs in ; the site answers: COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_ADMINACTIVATE_SUCCESS

And the new user receives an email confirming his registration.

Comment: Good you have found the problem.

Comment: Yes, but Guest is the right Viewing Access Level for Registration form and it fails !

Comment: Please, include `<jdoc:include type="mesage" />` in your index.php and see if there's any error.

Comment: Why invoke the Registration form Page in the link ?

Comment: If there's any error ,`<jdoc:include type="modules"  />` will show it to you. You can include this code in your index.php file of your template.

Comment: Christine, the registration form page in the link that you are talking about is, actually, a call to the function `activate()`in the controller `registration`. When a user clicks there, it should activate this user. You should also check the token, it may be causing the problem.

Comment: @ChristineDurand-Gasselin Point of order: if this post does not resolve your issue, it must not be posted as an answer.  If this post further clarifies the problem that you are experiencing, please transfer ALL of this content into your question body as an edit on the question.  This is part of the guidance in our [tour].  I can do all of these actions, but to better groom you in this community, I would prefer you to make this effort as part of your learning.  This post can be safely deleted after transferring its content.